# Android camera freeze issue

Tags: android, camera

I have implemented a custom camera application. I have followed the steps explained in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

On some devices, on taking a picture, my application freezes.

I get the following error message in logcat.

```
E/V4LCameraAdapter(2321): hardware/amlogic/camera/V4LCameraAdapter/V4LCameraAdapter.cpp:834 GetFrame - GetFrame: No buff for Dequeue

E/V4LCameraAdapter(2321): hardware/amlogic/camera/V4LCameraAdapter/V4LCameraAdapter.cpp:993 previewThread - Preview thread get frame fail, need sleep:33333
```

Is the error specific to the hardware of the device? Is there a way to set the camera parameter from SDK to avoid `No buff` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

Apparently this call back was choking the buffers with the data for each frame of the camera preview.

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
      public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
    //invalidate surfaceview
}
 });
```

Removing the callback worked for me.